# Is Krishna and Narayana both are same?

Tags: krishna, vishnu

Is the lord Krishna and Narayana both are same? Please anybody answer my question.

Comment: That depends on sect. Gaudiya Vaishnavaites say Krishna is Supreme and Narayana is Krishna's Avatar. Traditional Vaishnavaites believe that Krishna is paripoorna Avatar of Narayana.

Comment: Yes they are the same. Both names refer to 2 forms of the Supreme Lord. In terms of Tattva, there is really no difference between Visnu (Narayan) and His forms. In terms of rasa, there are some differences depending on the mood of the sampradaya you follow.

Comment: As @TheDestroyer, the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect, which the popular organization ISKCON belongs to, believes that Vishnu is an incarnation of Krishna. And most other Hindus believe that Krishna is an incarnation of Vishnu.  In any case, Narayana is just another name for Vishnu.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the quotes "mood of the sampradaya" as you mentioned. @Nitai dasa

Comment: @GopalBiswas For traditional Vaishnavs (followers of Ramanuja and  Madhavacharya), Sri Krsna is avatar of Lord Visnu. For the Gaudiyas and others (Vallabhacharya and Nimbarkas included) we believe that there is some difference between Krsna and Visnu (for us Krsna is higher in terms of rasa, or the consideration of mellows and Visnu is an avatar of Krsna). The Ramanandis on the other hand believe Lord Rama is source of both Visnu and Krsna. All Vaishnav schools believe in the superiority of Visnu  over all Gods, but there is difference in opinion of where various forms stand.

Comment: There is no difference, between lord Krishna and Lord Narayan, both are same only names are different. We(Ramanuja) believe Narayan/Vishnu is Supreme, and other sampardaye(Gaudiya,Ramanandi) believe Lord Krishna is Supreme or Lord Rama. But there is no meaning of debate on their differences,Because Whatever form you will worship it will goes to the same almighty lord Narayan/Krishna/Rama.

Comment: Krishna is the avatar of Narayana in Mahabharata. They are the same soul .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jaya Nitai!! Hi everyone.

So I was wondering this question posted, and today while reading Chaitanya Charitamrta (the biography of Lord Chaitanya), I found a beautiful conversation between Sri Chaitanya and one of His great disciples Venkata Bhatta. Srila Venkata Bhatta was a Sri Vaishnav who worshiped Sri Sri Lakshmi-Narayana, and he and Lord Chaitanya would often joke about whether Krsna or Narayan was "higher". Of course Lord Chaitanya bought up some of the traditional points we Gaudiyas bring up (about the qualities of Krsna, Lakshmi in Rasa Lila etc), but what stood out to me was the Lord's words at the end of the conversation. They were so beautiful...nearly made me cry. Coming from the mouth of a Vaishnav like Lord Chaitanya, I am sure other Vaishnav members would enjoy this:

> CC Madhya 9.152 — The Lord pacified Veṅkaṭa Bhaṭṭa by saying, “Actually whatever I have said is by way of jest. Now you can hear from Me the conclusion of the śāstras, in which every Vaiṣṇava devotee has firm faith.
>
> CC Madhya 9.153 — “There is no difference between Lord Kṛṣṇa and Lord Nārāyaṇa, for They are of the same form. Similarly, there is no difference between the gopīs and the goddess of fortune, for they also are of the same form.
>
> CC Madhya 9.154 — “The goddess of fortune enjoys the association of Kṛṣṇa through the gopīs. One should not differentiate between the forms of the Lord, for such a conception is offensive.
>
> CC Madhya 9.155 — “There is no difference between the transcendental forms of the Lord. Different forms are manifested due to different attachments of different devotees. Actually the Lord is one, but He appears in different forms just to satisfy His devotees.
>
> CC Madhya 9.156 — “ ‘When the jewel known as vaidūrya touches various other materials, it appears to be separated into different colors, and consequently its forms also appear different. Similarly, according to the meditational ecstasy of the devotee, the Lord, who is known as Acyuta [“the infallible one”], appears in different forms, although He is essentially one.’ ”
>
> CC Madhya 9.157 — Veṅkaṭa Bhaṭṭa then said, “I am an ordinary fallen living entity, but You are Kṛṣṇa, the Supreme Personality of Godhead Himself.
>
> CC Madhya 9.158 — “The transcendental pastimes of the Lord are unfathomable, and I do not know anything about them. Whatever You say I accept as the truth.
>
> CC Madhya 9.159 — “I have been engaged in the service of Lakṣmī-Nārāyaṇa, and it is due to Their mercy that I have been able to see Your lotus feet.
>
> CC Madhya 9.160 — “Out of Your causeless mercy You have told me of the glories of Lord Kṛṣṇa. No one can reach the end of the opulence, qualities and forms of the Lord.
>
> CC Madhya 9.161 — “I can now understand that devotional service unto Lord Kṛṣṇa is the supreme form of worship. Out of Your causeless mercy You have made my life successful simply by explaining the facts.”
>
> CC Madhya 9.162 — After saying this, Veṅkaṭa Bhaṭṭa fell down before the lotus feet of the Lord, and the Lord, out of His causeless mercy, embraced him.

In this discussion, the Lord quote a very important verse from Narada Pancaratra as shown below:

> *maṇir yathā vibhāgena
>   nīla-pītādibhir yutaḥ
>   rūpa-bhedam avāpnoti
>   dhyāna-bhedāt tathācyutaḥ*
>
> “ ‘When the jewel known as vaidūrya touches various other materials, it appears to be separated into different colors, and consequently its forms also appear different. Similarly, according to the meditational ecstasy of the devotee, the Lord, who is known as Acyuta [“the infallible one”], appears in different forms, although He is essentially one.’ ”

Lord Hari, who goes by many names (like Narayan,Krsna,Rama) etc is a great actor. His different avatars are like His different costumes that He displays to please His devotees. For His devotees in Vrndavana, who are not in the mood of awe and reverence, the Lord manifests as Sri Krsna in the form of a simple cowherd boy and performs earthly pastimes. For His devotees in Ayodhya and Vaikuntha, who are in the mood  of awe and reference, the Lord manifests beautiful forms like Rama and Visnu. Lord Rama battles so many great demons, and in this form, the devotees can enjoy the moods of war (called *Raudra rasa*). In-fact the Lord is such a good actor, that everyone may even forget sometimes that He is God (even the Lord Himself) due to the influence of His Yogamaya. This is confirmed in Srimad Bhagavatam by Kunti Devi:

> *māyā-javanikācchannam
>    ajñādhokṣajam avyayam
>   na lakṣyase mūḍha-dṛśā
>    naṭo nāṭyadharo yathā*
>
> "Being beyond the range of limited sense perception, You are the eternally irreproachable factor covered by the curtain of deluding energy. You are invisible to the foolish observer, exactly as an actor dressed as a player is not recognized."

Therefore, in actuality there is no difference between Krsna and Narayana. They are both two forms of the same personality. They are different due to the different pastimes they perform, their different associates and different forms. Also when we enter into discussions about "who came first, Visnu or Krsna?" we forget that both forms of the Lord are eternal and beyond the touch of time. All the *nitya avatars* of the Lord are eternally present in the spiritual world of Sri Vaikuntha, which is beyond the touch of material time (and hence conceptions of past present and future).

I know I have repeated what everyone has said, but I wanted to make an official answer with some quotes from scripture.

Comment: Jay Shree Krishna, Om Namo Narayan!!! All Vaisnav's ki jai..!!!